How to compare cases and controls after adjusting for age differences?
I have a dataset in which I have different measures (a, b, c) and two independent variables: D which is an independent binary variable representing cases (1) and controls (0), and age is another independent variable.
I want to look into the differences in y between cases and controls but they are not age-matched which is a problem in my case when looking into the differences.
How can I compare cases and controls after adjusting/correcting for the age difference?
I have received several suggestions but no one was able to explain why that was the right path to follow, and I am getting more and more confused. So far I tried:

GLM (a ~ age) and looked into the differences between the residuals based on D
GLM (a ~ age) and looked into the differences between the predicted values based on D
GLM (a ~ age + D + age*D) and looked at the p-value of the coeffiecients
GLM (a ~ age + D) and looked at the p-value of the coefficients

Does is it matter that a and c are also correlated with age?
Is one of the method above preferable to the others? If so can you explain me why? Is everything wrong and I should do something else?
I am using the statsmodels module from python.

The title of your question indicates that  age is used as a control variable: you want to control the effect of D for age differences between your cases and your controls, because age influences the dependent and is related to D also. The "net" effect of D is what you are looking for, that is, the difference between cases and controls given that they have the same age! This type of analysis is called Covariance Analysis, where D is the interesting factor and age is the covariate. So this leads to your 4th model, that is the one to go for.
Notice that there is more to look at than only the p values, as a comment says! The predicted difference between the two groups is obviously highly interesting and is what you want to know. This difference could also be used to derive the effect size Cohen's D, often reported in articles.
The third model would be needed only if you think that differences - in the dependent - between cases and controls are related to age: with increasing age, the difference between cases and controls changes linearly. But that seems not the situation you describe.
The first two approaches are not recommended at all.

+1.  Also, to look only or chiefly at "the p-value of the coefficients" misses much valuable information.  Hopefully one would look at the magnitude of the D coefficient; the extent to which this model is predictive; and the degree to which standard assumptions are met.

Ahhh you're right @rolando2!! Good to mention that too

Thank you so much! I realize that maybe I was not clear with my title maybe making it sound like I had already corrected or else but I think you solved my doubts.
You say "The predicted difference between the two groups is obviously highly interesting and is what you want to know. This difference could also be used to derive the effect size Cohen's D, often reported in articles." Do you mean the difference predicted from the fourth model ? Should I do the difference between those predictions between cases and controls and report that along with Cohen's D?

Also, sorry for the late reply!

Exactly, that is the difference controlled for the influence of age. Cohen's D is based on that difference.
